# Extraction of string and integer from txt

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner, reader, txt

I'm trying to make a simple scanner reader to read from a txt stored in C:\Users\james\Desktop\project\files\ and it's called data "data.txt", the thing is that the information stored is like this:

```
ASSETS    21
CHOROY 12
SHELL      9
```

So as you can see the spaces between the string and the integer that I want o extract are random. I was trying to make this:

```
public data(String s) //s is the name of the txt "data.txt"
{
    if (!s.equalsIgnoreCase("Null"))
    {
        try {
            File text = new File(s); 
            Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(text);
            while (fileReader.hasNextLine()) 
            { 
                String data = fileReader.nextLine();
                String[] dataArray = data.split(" ");
                String word = dataArray[0]; 
                String number = dataArray[1]; 
                int score = Integer.parseInt(number);
                addWord(word, score);
            }
            fileReader.close();
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("File not found");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Reading complete");
    }
```

But the split is only with one empty space between the string and the integer so I would like to know how can I extract that two things that are separated with any number of spaces in the same line. Example:

```
Line readed: HOUSE 1 -> String word = "HOUSE"; int score = "1";
Line readed: O          5 -> String word = "O"; int score = "5";
```

Comment: *But the split is only with one empty space between the string and the integer so I would like to know how can I extract that two things that are separated with any number of spaces in the same line.* - Replace `data.split(" ")` with `data.split("\\s+")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `data.split(" ")`

you can use

```
data.split("\\s+")
```

Also your function won't compile because it does not have any return.